# Sorting by input distribution

Tags: java, algorithm, function, sorting, logic

I have a problem that's bugging me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

> You are given an input array of integers and three sorting algorithms,
>   *(bubble sort, merge sort and quick sort (with middle pivot)*.
>
> Your job is to write a function that will decide which sorting
>   algorithm to use according to the *input distribution*.
>
> Some of the benchmarks can be:
>
> - Random
> - Nearly sorted (i.e. nearly sorted in ascending order)
> - Reversed (i.e. nearly sorted in descending order)
> - Few unique keys (i.e. contains repetitions due to few unique keys)
>
> Note: Benchmarks are your choices.

Comment: For nearly sorted and few unique keys, bubble sort might be reasonable.  For all the other use cases, a divide and conquer approach like merge sort or quick sort is the way to go.  For these other cases, bubble sort could hit `O(n^2)` running time.

Comment: For a simple measurement of how sorted the list is, you could calculate the sample covariance between the values and the position in the list. positive = mostly ascending, negative = mostly descending, 0 = random. It wouldn't work so well for some distributions of values however.

Comment: Yes, @TimBiegeleisen but how do you go about benchmarks that support the claim for *merge sort vs quick sort!*

Comment: Not sure...the `middle pivot` comment looks meaningful though.

Comment: See https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms, which gives descriptions of input conditions and has animations that show the algorithms working. In short, use Quicksort for random, bubble for nearly sorted ascending, and merge sort for the other two. That's assuming you're using a standard 2-way partitioning quicksort.

Comment: Thanks @JimMischel, and how would you go about checking if an array is *nearly sorted*? Which strategy or logic would you use?

Comment: http://shirleyisnotageek.blogspot.com/2015/04/determine-if-array-is-almost-sorted-if.html gives the basic algorithm, which is O(n).

Comment: I was able to implement the isNearlySorted function with the help of binary search. Basically I started by selecting a key at random and search it using binary search algorithm in order to check its availability in the list, the function executed with 90% plus accuracy.